# Jquery grep Vs each for better performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario to create two new arrays(based on certain conditions) from an existing array. I have two different ways to get my result.

1. Use Jquery grep() twice to filter the original array.

   ```
        var arrErrorRecs = [], arrWarningRecs = [];
        arrErrorRecs = jQuery.grep(aSelectedRecs,function(oItem){
            return oItem.Stat === "Error";
        });
        arrWarningRecs = jQuery.grep(aSelectedRecs,function(oItem){
            return oItem.Stat === "Warning";
        });
   ```
2. Use Jquery each() once and populate the two new arrays

   ```
       jQuery.each(aSelectedRecs, function(){
            if(this.MinPriceValidation === "Error"){
                arrErrorRecs.push(this);
            }else if(this.MinPriceValidation === "Warning"){
                arrWarningRecs.push(this);
            }
        });
   ```

I have an understanding that in this case Jquery.each would be best as it is looping the array only once. Please advise which is the most effective way for better performance.

Comment: Don't use jQuery at all, but the native `.filter` and `.forEach` methods

Comment: Is your `aSelectedRecs` really that big that it's worth micro-optimizing your code?

Comment: If performance is that important use neither `jquery` nor `forEach` nor `filter` nor `grep` but a classic `for` loop. But honestly you have to have like hundreds of thousands of entries to get a noticeable effect. So probably your best option is to use native `filter`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and comments. Understood that native filter will be better than jQuery fns.

Answer (score 0):

Since both code is O(n), I don’t think there is much problem with grep, but sure if the length of array is very huge, each would likely to be faster. But I believe not on the crazy difference though.